# Iterative search of a Teradata clob

Tags: for-loop, teradata, clob

We have an accountnumber stored in a Clob field in a table...we'll call it tbl_accountdetail.  I need to pull back all records from tbl_accountdetail if the account numbers are in the results from another query...we'll call it sourcequery.

I can do this individually for each account number with:

`Select * from Tbl_accountdetail where REGEXP_INSTR(CLOB,'accountnumber')>0`

Naturally, my first thought was to do a cursor and loop through each account number from the sourcequery.

```
Declare @accountnumber varchar(30)

Declare Err_Cursor Cursor for 
Select accountnumber from ErrorTable; 

Open Err_Cursor;
Fetch next from Err_Cursor into @accountnumber;
While @@Fetch_status = 0
Begin
    Select * from Tbl_accountdetail where REGEXP_INSTR(CLOB,@accountnumber)>0
    Fetch next from Err_Cursor into @accountnumber
End; 

Close Err_Cursor;
Deallocate Err_Cursor;
```

The more I read the more I'm confused about the best/most efficient way to get my desired results.

References to cursors all seem to require them to be included in a stored procedure and based on the simplicity, you wouldn't think this needs to be added to a sp.  References to macros all seem to be macros that need to update/insert,etc. which I don't need.  All I need to do is return the rows from Tbl_accountdetail that have the accountnumber somewhere in the clob.

I'm new to Teradata and Clobs. Can someone help me with the best way to search the clob? And to do so for a list of values?

Any help/suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How is your `CLOB` data structured?  Is the `accountnumber` field stored in a way that you can extract it using a searchable pattern -- i.e. `accountnumber=<10-digit-#>`?

If you want to search for multiple `accountnumber` values, then I think the best way is to extract the `accountnumber` value(s) from each `CLOB` and then search on them.  Something like:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Tbl_accountdetail 
WHERE <extracted_accountnumber> IN (
  SELECT account_number
  FROM account_table
)
```

You are right that cursors are only used in stored procedures.  The main purpose for them is to process each row of a result set individually and perform any additional logic, which you don't seem to need in your case.  You could either put the `SQL` into a macro or just run it as-is.

**Update**
Assuming you only have one `accountnum` value in your `CLOB` field with a format of `"accountnum": "123456789"`, you should be able to do something like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Tbl_accountdetail 
WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(myclob, '"accountnum":\s+"([0-9]+)"', 1, 1, NULL) IN (
  SELECT account_number
  FROM account_table
)
```

This should extract the first `accountnumber` match in your `CLOB` field and see if that value also exists in the `IN` sub-query.

I don't have a `TD` system to test on, so you may need to fiddle with the arguments a bit.  Just replace `myclob` with the name of your `CLOB` field and update the sub-query in the `IN()`.  Give that a try and let me know.

[SQL Fiddle (Oracle)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7ab9c/24)
[Regexp Tester](https://regex101.com/r/wwqYrR/2)
[Teradata - REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/bSkgRmSt8P48II0SKyyH3Q)

Comment: thank you for the feedback.  The clob is structured like a JSON message so it would be

Comment: Can you post some sample data?  Ideally, you would `CAST` from `CLOB` to `JSON` and use the built-in `JSON` functionality.  This may be tricky though, since LOBs can be finicky.

Comment: Sorry I got called into a meeting and didn't finish my reply.  DBA's have been unsuccessful with casting as JSON because of the size. But would love any suggestions you have to parse the clob to extract certain data:  Sample data follows:  "accountnum": "123456789" , "AcctSeriesID": "00" , "fileName": "Samplefilename.txt" ,

Comment: Or suggestions on how to a macro could accomplish the task.

Comment: How many account numbers are stored in this clob, is there a known maximum?

Comment: There is only one account number per clob.  The table construct is like: `id, state,company, loaddate,**Clob**,description` . I need to search the accountdetail table to find all the records where the accountnum (identified from another query) exists in the clob.  Ideally, I would love to do exactly as you said and extract the accountnum from the clob into another table to query at will.  What I can't get my head around is how to go through the table one row for a specified list of accounts and either pull the data out of the clob or to search the clob. i'm probably over thinking it.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tag @ravioli  in my last response.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.  Let me know if it works for you.